# Is there any way to keep WIFI always ON, ignoring even the Power mode set by the user?

Tags: android, android-networking

I am making an android app which requires WIFI to be always ON even if phone gets locked. Also, power mode selected by user shouldn't make WIFI to turn OFF. For example, if user selects "Power Saving" mode than OS will automatically turn OFF the WIFI which I want to ignore & just keep it ON forever?

Is it achievable?

Comment: I'm sure you cannot breach the privacy of the device from inside an ordinary app (which you place on Google Play). You might be able to do this on the OS level on a rooted phone.

Comment: Okay so it is achievable If I am not uploading my app to playstore?

Comment: You cannot do that cause as a `power saver` It will stop all `background processes`
and from there your background app `execution` to **Enabling Wifi Forever** will end up to stop too

Comment: Okay... thanks Kira!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that you can do is [use `WifiLock`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.WifiLock.html). This keeps the WiFi radio on when it was already on. However:

- It does not override manual user control (e.g., airplane mode)
- AFAIK it will not change [full Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) behavior, where network access is suspended (though the user could add your app to the battery optimization whitelist)
- Some device manufacturers have added more aggressive power management features, and it is possible that `WifiLock` is ignored for them
- Users may get irritated if they feel that you are using an excessive amount of power, and users can express their irritation in a variety of ways, few of which are pleasant

Comment: Thanks you for all the suggestions, so as per the reviews it can't be achieved in normal scenarios.